# Get multiple values from dynamically generated items with mojolicious

Tags: html, forms, perl, mojolicious

I'm developing a small webpage that reads data from a couple of files and render it into a website. In that website, user must be able to choose one or more items and perform some work with those (changing name, append values, etc). I've been able to do most of the work, but now I'm facing a problem. I have this form:

```
<div id="inside">
    % foreach my $value ( @{ stash('tagitems') } ) {
        <div id="inside">
            %= form_for 'save' => begin
                <input type="radio" name="radioid">
                %= hidden_field 'id' => $indexnum
                %= input_tag 'tag', value=>"$value", size=>"50%"
                %= submit_button 'Save changes'
                <%= select_field 'levelSelected' => [ @{ stash('levelsArray') }] %>
                <button type="submit" form="insertForm">Insert</button>
            % end
            <form action="/insert" id="insertForm"></form>

        </div>
        % $indexnum += 1;
    % }
```

I'm getting everything rendered and it's ok. I can use the save form (that routes to a sub that changes it's name. the problem is with the *inserform*. The insert is supposed to check every radio button that it's checked and take the value *tag* and *levelSelected*.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

**Edit**:

I've multiple instances that looks like this:
[image]

So, I need to have just one insert button (instead of one per item) that find out whatever radio button is checked and get info of all checked items (tag and levelSelected) when clicked the submit button.

**EDIT2 - CODE THAT WORKS**:
I've found a way to do it. The code is here:

```
%= form_for 'save' => begin
    <button type="submit" formaction="insert">Insert</button>
    % foreach my $value ( @{ stash('tagitems') } ) {
        <div id="inside">
            <input type="checkbox" name="insert">
            %= hidden_field 'id' => $indexnum
            %= input_tag 'tag', value=>"$value", size=>"50%"
            <button type="submit" formaction="save">save</button>
            <%= select_field 'levelSelected' => [ @{ stash('levelsArray') }] %>
        </div>
    % }
    % end
</form>
```

Comment: Could you perhaps [edit] the question to show the HTML snippet you are trying to create? I'm not sure I understand your problem description.

Comment: Already done, hope it make it easier to understand now.

Comment: You can answer your own question. Please move the working code from the question into an answer, and explain why it's working. You can accept your own answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using this piece of code:

```
%= form_for 'save' => begin
    <button type="submit" formaction="insert">Insert</button>
    % foreach my $value ( @{ stash('tagitems') } ) {
        <div id="inside">
            <input type="checkbox" name="insert">
            %= hidden_field 'id' => $indexnum
            %= input_tag 'tag', value=>"$value", size=>"50%"
            <button type="submit" formaction="save">save</button>
            <%= select_field 'levelSelected' => [ @{ stash('levelsArray') }] %>
        </div>
    % }
    % end
</form>
```

Then, in the controller:

```
get '/insert' => sub {
    my $mojo = shift;
    my @all_values;

    foreach my $field ('id', 'insert', 'tag', 'levelSelected') {
       @all_values = @{$mojo->every_param($field)};
        print Dumper (@all_values);
  }
};
```